# C: "array type has incomplete element type" when using array of struct without typedef

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, incomplete-type

**Problem:** The following code snippet compiles well (where both struct types are typedefed):

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    float b;
} member_struct;

typedef struct {
    int a;
    double b;
    member_struct c;
} outside_struct;

outside_struct my_struct_array[4];
```

However, if the typedef of the "outside_struct" is dropped:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    float b;
} member_struct;

struct {
    int a;
    double b;
    member_struct c;
} outside_struct;

struct outside_struct my_struct_array[4];
```

I get the error:
`"array type has incomplete element type 'struct outside_struct'".`
And if I also drop the typedef of "member_struct", I get an extra error:
`"field 'c' has incomplete type"`

**Question:** Why it happens? Is using typedef strictly necessary here? In my code, I otherwise never use typedef for structure types, so I am looking for a way to avoid that, if possible.

Comment: There is no type called `struct outside_struct` in the second snippet. You have one instance of an anonymous struct called `outside_struct` - it is not a type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this declaration

```
struct {
    int a;
    double b;
    member_struct c;
} outside_struct;
```

there is declared the object `outside_struct` of unnamed structure type. Neither structure with the name `struct outside_struct` is declared.

So the compiler issues an error in this declaration of an array

```
struct outside_struct my_struct_array[4];
```

because in this declaration there is introduced the type specifier `struct outside_struct` that is not defined. That is in this declaration the type specifier `struct outside_struct` is an incomplete type.

You may not declare an array with an incomplete element type.

Instead of declaring the object `outside_struct`  of an unnamed structure you need to declare a structure with the same tag name as

```
struct  outside_struct {
    int a;
    double b;
    member_struct c;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I got confused by the compiler error, as if I had not specified the internal fields of the struct.

Comment: @kmalarski I guess the array definition also acts as a declaration for `struct outside_struct` (which does not collide with the struct instance `outside_struct` because of the struct keyword) and in that sense, the compiler error is accurate, however without knowing that, it can be confusing indeed!

Answer (score 2):

If you drop the typedef, you need to add a struct tag instead: `struct outside_struct { ... };`

Answer (score 0):

Typedef is used to create an additional name (alias) for another data type.

```
typedef int myInt; //=>equivalent to "int"
myInt index = 0; //=>equivalent to "int index = 0;"
```

It's the same logic for struct.

```
typedef struct myStruct {} myStruct_t; //=> equivalent to "struct myStruct {};"
myStruct_t myStructVariable; //=> equivalent to "struct myStruct myStructVariable;"
```

syntaxe = "typedef  type  newAlias;"

"**myStruct{}**" is a new type that contain all the type that you want (int, char...)